# unity3d: how to use OpenFolderPanel

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity. I want to try [this tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel.html) but I failed.
I created a GameObject - UI - Button, and tried to add script to Canvas. But I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E9Zk.png).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I know your mistake. When you create a c# script, do as follows (if you want to attach it to a gameobject).

**1) Select the gameobject in the heirarchy. 
   2) Click add component in the inspector window. 
   3) Type in the name of your new script, and Unity will generate a basic script derived from MonoBehaviour automatically.**

BTW, game objects have monobehaviour derived scripts on them (in singleplayer). The script you are using is derived from EditorWindow, not MonoBehaviour. Personally, I have not used a custom editor, but I think the script you are using should work automatically without having to attach it to a gameobject.

Answer (score 1):

OpenFolderPanel is an **Editor script** which lets people to make some customized function for **Unity Efitor**.

If you want to click button to show file dialog in your game, you can try  [StandaloneFileBrowser](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser)